# zip ファイル内の複数のファイルの読み取り方法

Tags: python, excel

zip ファイル中のファイルのデータを解析したいです。そのためにはそれらを読み取らなければいけないと考え、色々やってみましたがなかなか上手くいきません。特定の一個は読み取れますが、繰り返しやろうと挑戦すると上手くいきません。

中のファイルは100ほどあるので一気に読み取れる方法が知りたいです。

以下のコードで恐らくzipfile 内の‘xlsx2/1093.xlsx’ が開けていると思います。なので、これをfor文でループさせればzipfile内のファイルを開けると考えました。
この時、for 文で変えるべきなのはファイル名の数字の部分だと思います。なので、先にfor 文を使用してファイル名を変えようとしているのですが上手くいきません。

という状況です。ご教授よろしくお願いいたします。

```
with ZipFile('xlsx2.zip') as zf:
    with zf.open('xlsx2/1093.xlsx','r') as f:
        for line in f:
            print()
```

Comment: 「繰り返しやろうと挑戦すると上手くいきません」について詳しく書いていただくことは出来ますか？

Comment: ファイル名一覧の取得の後の処理 …
`for line in f:` 一行ずつ読み取るようですが, `'xlsx2/1093.xlsx'`のファイル名から察するにバイナリファイルなので無理だと思われます。
xlsx使って何か行いたいのであれば, 質問に詳細記すか 別質問にしたほうがよいかも

Answer (score 1):

zipfileからファイル名一覧を取得するには以下の種類があります

- `ZipFile.infolist()`
  アーカイブに含まれる各メンバの [`ZipInfo`](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipInfo) オブジェクトからなるリストを返します。既存のアーカイブファイルを開いている場合、リストの順番は実際の ZIP ファイル中のメンバの順番と同じになります。
- `ZipFile.namelist()`
  アーカイブメンバの名前のリストを返します。

参考: [zipfile --- ZIP アーカイブの処理](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/zipfile.html)

重複するメンバーがあるなら `infolist()` 一択です
そうでないならどちら使ってもよいでしょう

また Zipファイルメンバーの読み込みには,  `open`はあってもなくてもどちらでも構わない (以下のように, `read` 1回だけで済むような場合には)
(これは `namelist()`使用時でも同様)

```py
import zipfile
with zipfile.ZipFile(zipfname) as zf:
    for inf in zf.infolist():
        v = zf.read(inf)
        print(inf.filename, len(v))
```

`namelist()` は, `infolist()`を元に, (内部では)利用するたび毎回生成されるので微妙に遅い
(zipfileの容量やメンバー数が少なければ, 大して影響しない)

```py
import zipfile
with zipfile.ZipFile(zipfname) as zf:
    for fname in zf.namelist():
        with zf.open(fname) as fp:
            v = fp.read()
            print(fname, len(v))
```

Answer (score 0):

※コメントと @oriri さんの回答を参考にさせていただいて回答を修正しました。

[`ZipFile.namelist()`](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.namelist)または[`ZipFile.infolist()`](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.infolist)を使用すると、zipファイルの中身を一覧で取り出すことができます。

これらの関数は拡張子を限定せずにすべてのファイルを取り出すので、for文内の条件分岐などを使って必要なファイル以外を読み込まないようにしてください。
下記のサンプルコードでは、zip内にある拡張子が`.xlsx`のファイルを[openpyxl](https://pypi.org/project/openpyxl/)で読み取って、最初のシートのA1を読み取っています。

**サンプルコード**

```
from zipfile import ZipFile
import openpyxl
import io

with ZipFile('xlsx2.zip') as zf:
    for inf in zf.infolist():
        print('ファイル名:', inf.filename)
        # 拡張子が.xlsx以外のファイルはスキップ
        if not inf.filename.lower().endswith('.xlsx'):
            continue
        # バイト配列をエクセル化
        xlsx = io.BytesIO(zf.read(inf))
        wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(xlsx)
        # 最初のシートのA1を読み取る
        print('A1の値:', wb.worksheets[0]["A1"].value)
```

ちなみに`BadZipFile: File is not a zip file`はxlsxファイルが不正なファイルの場合(例えば`.csv`や`.xls`ファイルの拡張子を書き換えただけなど)にも発生します。
条件分岐してもエラーが解消されない場合は、エラーの発生するxlsxファイルがエクセルで正しく読み込めるかをご確認ください。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
私がやるとwbの場所に赤線が引かれ’BadZipFile: File is not a zip file’ と言われてしまいます。質問ばかりで申し訳ないのですが、原因が何かわかりますか。もし、わかるようでしたら、教えていただきたいです。よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 回答を修正しました。